# Unittests not run with python -m unittest command

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest, unit-testing

I have such structure

```
app/
    __init__.py
    phonebook.py
    test_phonebook.py
```

Being in `app` directory I can run tests in terminal with `python test_phonebook.py`

But why tests do not run when I enter`python -m unittest` being in `app` directory?
I see message that 0 tests run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run multiple `test_*.py` files by hand, you have to create `unittest.TestLoader` to select tests and run that with `unittest.TestRunner`.

For example you can add `__main__.py` to your app

```
import unittest
import os
def run(verbosity=2):
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=verbosity).run(suite)
run()
```

and launch it with

```
$>python -m app
```

So it will discover all your tests inside `app` and launch them.

Comment: looks like hack, if there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Its the way `unittest` intended to be used, according to unittest docs. And i dont know about 'cleaner' but its a pythonic way, because `Explicit is better than implicit`